# Use point index in geometry node distribution

Tags: modeling, node-editor, procedural, geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I'm playing with geometry nodes here and I'm trying to create a way to kinda script the position of each point... for that i'm thinking of creating an attribute that would work as index, something that I could use later for a function based distribution...

As a simple example: I would like to take every point and add its index to its x position, while setting the y and z position to 0, just to create a straight line.

Is there any way I could do something like that ?

Comment: Hello, at the moment it's not possible, you can kind of emulate that if your input geometry is regularly spaced in 3D space, using their coordinates to assign an incremented index, but the actual vertex indices is not exposed. I'm sure it will be in a future version though

Comment: Have you tried this again using Blender 3.0 geometry nodes? Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Xlf.png) what you're looking for. It has problems with the edge connectivity in the resulting geometry, but might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following way you can solve it starting from version **3.0**:

[image]

The *X-position* is simply added to the index with the math node `Add`, packed into a new vector and with `Set Position` the individual points are repositioned accordingly.